# How to pass data to servlet from jqueryTable

Tags: jquery, servlets, datatable

```
    $("#example").dataTable( {
        "bProcessing": false,
        "lengthMenu": [ [4, 10, 50, -1], [4, 10, 50, "All"] ],
        "bServerSide": false,
        "sort": "position",
        "sAjaxSource": "./PaginationServlet?custom=name",

        'autoWidth': false,
        "aoColumns": [
            { "mData": "name" },
            { "mData": "ParsedSet","render":simple},
            { "mData": "RetrievedSet","render":simple },
            { "mData": "checkkey","render": simple_checkbox },
            { "mData": "MissingSet","render":simple },


        ]
    } );

} );
```

Here i am passing the value 'name' to the attribute 'custom'. However, i want name to be a 'variable' . So how do i pass a variable for custom.

Comment: where is custom attribute?

Comment: After the source URL , ./PaginationServlet?custom=

Answer (score 1):

You can concatenate name variable as shown below

```
var nameValue = 'name';

    $("#example").dataTable( {
            "bProcessing": false,
            "lengthMenu": [ [4, 10, 50, -1], [4, 10, 50, "All"] ],
            "bServerSide": false,
            "sort": "position",
            "sAjaxSource": "./PaginationServlet?custom="+nameValue,// add variable here

            'autoWidth': false,
            "aoColumns": [
                { "mData": "name" },
                { "mData": "ParsedSet","render":simple},
                { "mData": "RetrievedSet","render":simple },
                { "mData": "checkkey","render": simple_checkbox },
                { "mData": "MissingSet","render":simple },


            ]
        } );

    } );
```